# How to add field default values for various methods in Spring Data Rest?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I want to add 2 date fields to my entity

- creationDate
- lastModificationDate

How can I define default values for them in Spring Data REST so that creationDate gets it default value(current date) when I create the entity, and the lastModificationDate gets its value as current date for each put request for that entity?

Comment: any reason not to delegate this to your database ?

Comment: i guess no, but if possible, this way i'd have all the logic in one place

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this to your model.

```
@PrePersist
void onCreate() {
  this.setCreationDate(new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime()));
}

@PreUpdate
void onPersist() {
  this.setLastModificationDate(new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define listener:

```
public class EntityListener {

    @PrePersist
    public void beforeSave(Entity entity) {
        entity.setCreationDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        entity.setLastModificationDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void beforeUpdate(Entity entity) {
        entity.setLastModificationDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```